how to avoid execution in a block in bison
so i am facing a problem where it executes the PRINT command though return value is false
eg:
func main(){
    a -> 9;
    print ( a );
    if (a > 10){
        print ( 99 );
    }   
}

so 99 shouldn't be printed as expected but it prints , how can i avoid it?
Result: 9
Result: 99
statements : empty
statements : statement statements
Condition false, skipping if block
statements : empty
statements : statement statements
statements : statement statements
statements : statement statements
function : FUNC IDENT LPAR RPAR LCURL statements RCURL
functions : empty
functions : function functions
program : functions

    %{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "variables.h"

    #define MAX_VARS 100

    typedef struct {
        char *name;
        int value;
    } Var;

    Var vars[MAX_VARS];
    int var_count = 0;

    int yylex();
    void yyerror(const char *s);

    int get_var_value(const char *name);
    void set_var_value(const char *name, int value);
    %}

    %union {
        int ival;
        char *sval;
    }

    %token <sval> IDENTIFIER
    %token <ival> INTEGER
    %token FUNC
    %token LPAR
    %token RPAR
    %token LCURL
    %token RCURL
    %token PRINT
    %token SEMICOLON
    %token PLUS
    %token IS
    %token MINUS
    %token MULTIPLY
    %token DIVIDE
    %token GREATER
    %token LESS
    %token EQUAL
    %token DOUBLE_EQUAL
    %token IF

    %left PLUS MINUS
    %left MULTIPLY DIVIDE

    %type <ival> expression
    %type <ival> statement
    %type <ival> statements
    %type <ival> function
    %type <ival> functions
    %type <ival> program
    %type <ival> var_decl
    %type <ival> condition 
    %start program

    %%

    program : functions { printf("program : functions\n"); }
            ;

    functions : function functions { printf("functions : function functions\n"); }
            | /* empty */ { printf("functions : empty\n"); }
            ;

    function : FUNC IDENTIFIER LPAR RPAR LCURL statements RCURL { printf("function : FUNC IDENT LPAR RPAR LBIG statements RBIG\n"); }
            ;

    statements : statement statements { printf("statements : statement statements\n"); }
            | /* empty */ { printf("statements : empty\n"); }
            ;

    statement : PRINT LPAR expression RPAR SEMICOLON { printf("Result: %d\n", $3); }
            | var_decl SEMICOLON {}
            | IF LPAR condition RPAR LCURL statements RCURL {
                if ($3 == 1) {
                    printf("Condition true\n");
                } else if ( $3 == 0) {
                    printf("Condition false,skipping if block\n");                
                    //skip the {} block of the if condition 
                }
            }
            ;

    condition : expression GREATER expression { $$ = $1 > $3; }
            | expression LESS expression { $$ = $1 < $3; }
            | expression DOUBLE_EQUAL expression { $$ = $1 == $3; }
            ;
                /* toke $1      **   toke $3 */
    var_decl : IDENTIFIER IS INTEGER { set_var_value($1, $3); $$ = $3; }
            ;

    expression : expression PLUS expression { $$ = $1 + $3; }
            | expression MINUS expression { $$ = $1 - $3; }
            | expression MULTIPLY expression { $$ = $1 * $3; }
            | expression DIVIDE expression { $$ = $1 / $3; }
            | INTEGER { $$ = $1; }
            | IDENTIFIER { $$ = get_var_value($1); }
            ;

    %%

    int main(void) {
        return yyparse();
    }

    void yyerror(const char *s) {
        printf("ERROR: %s\n", s);
    }


I am noob at coding and i am just trying to learn bison and flex ,  if the condition is false not to execute the statements inside the if block
and got to next block
eg:
func main(){
    a -> 9;
    print ( a );
    if (a > 10){
        print ( 99 );
    }   
b -> 10;
print( b );
}


int get_var_value(const char *name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < var_count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(vars[i].name, name) == 0) {
            return vars[i].value;
        }
    }
    printf("Variable %s not found\n", name);
    return 0;
}

void set_var_value(const char *name, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < var_count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(vars[i].name, name) == 0) {
            vars[i].value = value;
            return;
        }
    }
    // Add new variable if it does not exist
    vars[var_count].name = strdup(name);
    vars[var_count].value = value;
    var_count++;
}



Among other things, you have not shown get_var_value or set_var_value, so we cannot see if they are properly implemented. Debugging questions on Stack Overflow should include a [mre]. Use a debugger or insert printf statements to see what the value of a is when a > 10 is analyzed.

sorry sir , here are the functions
int get_var_value(const char *name) {     for (int i = 0; i < var_count; i++) {         if (strcmp(vars[i].name, name) == 0) {             return vars[i].value;         }     }     printf("Variable %s not found\n", name);     return 0; }

void set_var_value(const char *name, int value) {
for (int i = 0; i < var_count; i++) {
if (strcmp(vars[i].name, name) == 0) {
vars[i].value = value;
return;
}
}
// Add new variable if it does not exist
vars[var_count].name = strdup(name);
vars[var_count].value = value;
var_count++;
}

@IllTime00qw, those should be edited into the question, not presented as comments.

For a language of any significant complexity, it is typical to separate parsing the program from executing it.  In such an approach, the parser generates a data structure representing the program, usually in the form of an abstract syntax tree (AST), which is then the input to a function that produces the appropriate behavior.
If you want to execute directly from the parser then that's possible to some extent, but you would have to maintain more state.  The parser cannot just skip parts of the input.  It needs to parse everything, so as to know, for example, where your conditional block ends.  Thus, if you want to implement conditionals directly in the parser then you will need to maintain additional data that can inform parser actions about when they appear inside a conditional block whose condition evaluates to false.  For instance, the action associated with your PRINT statement production would use that data to avoid executing the printf call.
Note well that loops and subprograms are a different matter.  The parser will push through the input linearly. It will not loop back to re-parse input that it has already processed.  To implement a loop, a reusable function, or the like, then, you need to create and manage some kind of stored representation of the behavior of the loop or function body that you can use later to produce that behavior.
